# Get the current hierarchy php page

Tags: template-hierarchy

Does exist some way to get the current searched hierarchy php page in `Wordpress`?
I've set a default category to my posts named `post` so if I digit `http://site.com/post` which php page is searched in the `hierarchy`?

It would be great to get the current page searched.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand your question. Are you talking about *static pages*, or *single blog post pages*? If you're talking about *static pages*, then what does your default category have to do with the question? If you're talking about *single blog post pages*, what does hierarchy have to do with the question (perhaps the *template* hierarchy)? And in either case, what does *search* have to do with the question?

Comment: Poorly written, have no way to determine what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Well I try to reformulate the question, I know if I've created a `Custom Post Type` with the `slug` named `photo` Wordpress looking for the page `single-photo.php`, does exists some way to print which page it's looking for?

Comment: So, you want to know what *template page* is currently being displayed, within the *template hierarchy*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're wanting to determine which *template page* is currently being displayed, within the *template hierarchy*, the easiest way to do so is via the output of `body_class()`.

However, if you need to return this information programmatically, the easiest way might be to call [`get_body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class), and then evaluate the array of classes returned. Given the way that [`get_body_class()` steps through](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L401) each query conditional itself (and [the template loader does likewise](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L22)), I'm guessing that core doesn't have a more abstracted approach.